# Not getting correct expected output on diceroll

Tags: c++, c++14

I am currently working on this program to roll 2 dice. My program works however, for some reason my expected output is coming out as 0.000% for all roll sums instead of what it should be. I am sure I am overlooking something but I have no idea what. Any help is much appreciated!

[image: Current Expected]

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
const int ROLLS = 36000;
const int SIZE  = 13;
const int CW    = 10;

// array 'expected' contains counts for the expected number of times
// each sum occurs in 36 rolls

int expected[SIZE]= {0,0,1/36,1/18,1/12,1/9,5/36,1/6,5/36,1/9,1/12,1/18,1/36};

int sum [SIZE] = {0};

int die1;
int die2;

srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(nullptr)));

for (int i = 0; i <=ROLLS; ++i) {
    die1 = 1 + rand() % 6;
    die2 = 1 + rand() % 6;
    sum[die1+die2]++;
}

cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(3);

cout << setw(CW) << "Sum" << setw(CW) << "Total"
     << setw(CW) << "Expected" << setw(CW) << "Actual" << endl;

for (int j = 2; j < SIZE; ++j) {
    cout << setw(CW) << j << setw(CW) << sum[j]
         << setw(CW-1) << (100.0 * expected[j] / 36) << '%'
         << setw(CW-1) << (100.0 * sum[j] / ROLLS) << '%' << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do remember that `int` is an *integer* type, and can't have decimals? And that operations on integers (like e.g. `1/36`) also results in integers?

Comment: **WARNING**: Using [`rand()` can be highly problematic](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and you’re strongly encouraged to use an appropriate [random number generator facility in the Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that produces high-quality random values. Your use of `time(NULL)` as a random number seed means that this will produce identical results if run in the same second, and on many platforms `rand()` is *barely* random at all. Consider using `std::uniform_int_distribution`

Answer (score 4):

The type of `expected` is `int`, which means it's an integer. The results of all of your divisions are truncated to the lowest integer, which is always 0.

You need to:

1. Declare `expected` as a real number type, such as `float` or `double`
2. Use the correct literals to make the division produce real numbers, e.g. `5.0f/36` or `5.0/36`.

Comment: It might make sense to express the `expected` values as integers presumed to have a common divisor, then cast to `double` and divide by a constant in the output calculation. `1/12` becomes `3/36` becomes `3`.

Comment: I tried this however now I am getting 12 implicit conversion warnings.

Comment: Did you do step #2. If you just changed the type to double as in step #1  it does not fix the integer division `1/36` problem. The double will still be 0.

Comment: Oh yeah, Im sorry I actually forgot about that part! It goes without saying I am pretty new to this... However, now I am getting expected percentages that are just wrong i.e. [0.077%, 0.154%,0.231%,..etc]

Comment: @FlashpointPrdx Well, that's a mathematics error. You state in the comments that `expected` is supposed to be the number of times the sum is expected to appear in 36 rolls, which would align with the fact that you `cout` `100 * expected[j] / 36`. But then you have things like `expected[2] == 1./36` instead of `expected[2] == 1`. Decide whether `expected` is supposed to be the number of times the value is expected to appear per 1 roll or per 36 rolls, and then use that consistently.

Comment: Why do you have the 36 here: `(100.0 * expected[j] / 36)`